# scaling and centering UITextFields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a loginviewcontroller, with 2 UITextField, username, password, a button and a UIImageView. This should work over a portrait and landscape mode. However in my landscape mode I want to be able to center all of these elements. How do I do this? Also I would need to scale the size of the elements so that it is appropriate.

I tried playing with the springs and it looks totally weird as everything is streched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the "contentMode" on your views. This will tell the super view how the subviews should be scaled and positioned when redraw or layout happens.
You can also manually position and set the textAlignment etc. in the:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {

        //align in one way
        return YES;
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

        //align in a different way
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: yes I understand that I can center it using this method, I can do textview.center = view.center, however I can't seem to get the correct x and y center..

Comment: I updated my answer a bit, it was missing the return BOOL. The method is named "shouldAutorota....." this means it happens before any rotation takes place. There are other delegate methods like didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation that happens after the rotation takes place. If you reference the view.center before it rotates it will essentially give you the "previous" coordinates. If you do it after the rotation they will be updated. I was answering as if you knew the exact coordinates and wanted to provide them yourself, sorry about that:)